# What can we do if someone overdoes with gratitude?

Tags: discussion

It is good when people show their gratitude accepting answers. But how to deal with those who want to overgive their thankfulness and start upvoting the helper person's answers in despite of favor to them personally?

I know that serial up-voting rolls back, even with damage to reputation… That's why I think my question is applicable to many users.

Comment: I've done something similar before, and I've only recently realised the ramifications. However, I think there's a legitimate reason for my actions. I've thought, "great answer", and been curious as to their other activity. Then, if they have other good answers, I've upvoted (only) those. Two things have happened here: curiosity to their answers in general; and an unsurprising correlation between a good answer, and… good answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes people simply do not realize they are indirectly hurting the system by voting for a *user*  rather than rewarding good *content.* You can simply explain this to them. They should also know that they can actually be *hurting* the user when the system detects this activity and their well-meaning votes are removed in bulk.

The system has processes in place to detect various types of targeted voting between users and groups of users. But if you suspect a user is disproportionately voting for a *user* rather than voting broadly for good *posts,* please feel free to pass on an appropriate excerpt from the guidance they will receive if they get caught up in this activity.

> Dear {user},
>
> We recently noticed a substantial number of votes on your account to or from *specific users*. Please note that votes on Ask Ubuntu should be cast to reflect the quality, accuracy, and relevance of the posts being voted on.
>
> While we encourage everyone to up-vote great posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the post, **not the person that wrote it.** Please refrain from targeting specific users' posts when voting. Stack Exchange strives to ensure that everyone who has a question sees the best information first; intentionally voting for content simply for the benefit of your family, friends or co-workers unfairly skews that system, and can result in a lengthy timed suspension for all concerned.
>
> The offending votes have been invalidated. In the future, please ask people that you know to refrain from voting for your contributions simply because you wrote them. Additionally, please don't engage in this behavior yourself.
>
> <irrelevant stuff about remediation removed>